# Mounting linux container on windows host

Tags: docker

I am new to docker and exploring how I can use it for development. I cannot figure out how to mount a volume. Below is the error I get, even after I have shared my drives in the docker settings. Hope someone can give me some guidance on this.

```
docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/C/Users/TanmayDharmaraj/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/Docker/Js-mounted': mkdir /C/Users/TanmayDharmaraj/Documents: permission denied.
```

The docker command i am using is

```
docker run -v "C:\Users\TanmayDharmaraj\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Docker\Js-mounted":/code js
```

Below is the docker file I am using

```
FROM node:6.10
ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

#copy everything to /code including node_modules (see above). Should use .dockerignore to remove node_modules
COPY . .

#Can't run npm install for now as there is a bug in gulp-spsync-creds. So for now, just copy over all node_modules
#RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Did you add drive C to the shared drives in the docker for windows settings?

Comment: [Here is the step by step instructions](https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c#.5mjrv9179)

Comment: Ok, I had previously shared the drive but i did some fiddling around and probably resetting the credentials worked. I can now mount but my `COPY . .` command does nothing at all. I end up with an empty directory. I am happy to open a new question if that would help.

Comment: I have same error when start my docker these two days, it is a shared drive issue.
I have summary those issue in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51799334/2224000).