# Encountered errors while bringing up the project

Tags: docker, permissions, docker-compose, mkdir, permission-denied

I have a problem when I am installing odoo 10 by docker. I can't compose up `docker.error` while creating mount source path.

People can help me!

Thanks!

> ERROR: for dockercomposeodoo100_odoo10_1  Cannot start service odoo10:
>   b"error while creating mount source path
>   '/host_mnt/c/Users/hoang/Downloads/docker-compose-odoo-10.0/o_etc':
>   mkdir /host_mnt/c/Users/hoang/Downloads: permission denied"
>
> ERROR: for odoo10  Cannot start service odoo10: b"error while creating
>   mount source path
>   '/host_mnt/c/Users/hoang/Downloads/docker-compose-odoo-10.0/o_etc':
>   mkdir /host_mnt/c/Users/hoang/Downloads: permission denied" ERROR:
>   Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Answer (score 1):

It might be this Windows specific behavior/bug https://stackoverflow.com/a/43767642/89769

(Guess from the path in the error message)

Answer (score 0):

It is shared drive issue, could be solved by following steps. My example are based on Docker on windows, and Symantec Endpoint Protection as firewall.

1. Mount to other directories

   Please follow setup steps on [Docker on windows](https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c) or [quickstart](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#general), when you need mount directories outside C:\Users on Win 10.
2. Turn off firewall

   Type follow command in Windows 10 search window to turn off SEP

> smc -stop

Re-enable firewall by

> smc -start

3. Check standard shared drive works

Docker provide sample check command under `Shared Drives` tab

> docker run --rm -v c:/Users:/data alpine ls /data

If the command output is empty then there are set up issue, because C:\Users is no way be  empty.

To reapply shared drives you can use either way

```
A. Reapply shared drives by uncheck `Shared` in Shared Drives Tab, then click [Apply] button
B. Reset credentials, you need retype user id and password setup on step 1
```

4. Check shared drive outside C:\Users
For example, my directory is C:\Proj\GitHub then

> docker run --rm -v c:/Proj/GitHub:/data alpine ls /data

If output is empty then it is a Windows authorization issue. The **Administrator** role may not enough to access the directory by setup in step 1. You need shared to user ID by `File Explorer`. Click the directory and show context menu by click right button. Choice 
`Give access to`>`Specific people`, then grant to user id defined in step 1.